# Global variable won't change in function

Tags: javascript, variables, global, local

To practice coding, I am making a virtual casino, with a roulette wheel.  For simplicity's sake, the wheel currently has only 4 sections, instead of the usual 37.  I'm trying to have a "money" variable that adjusts every time the player spins the roulette wheel.  IE if the player bets $10 on number 4 and loses, they will now have $190 instead of $200.  The problem is, the "money" variable does not seem to change, even though its a global variable.

Here's a piece of my code.  What is the problem?

```
var money = 200;

function spin(){
  var landing = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;   

  var nsvalue = parseInt(document.regular_roulette.num_select.value);

  var betvalue = parseInt(document.regular_roulette.bet.value);

  if (landing === nsvalue) {
    alert("You win $" + betvalue * 3);

    money = money + (betvalue * 3);
  } else {
    alert("You lose $" + betvalue);

    money = money - betvalue;
  }
}

document.write("You currently have $" + money);
```

Comment: How are you calling `document.write()`? You should be calling that (or updating the page in some other way) in your function itself. Otherwise you only output to the page once; before any betting has occurred. You need to update the output **after** `money` has updated.

Comment: Are you sure you call `spin()` method from somewhere? Also the problem could be in `document.regular_roulette.bet.value` -- it could be zero/undefined...

Comment: Note that `document.write`  will overwrite your document...

Comment: Note as posted IF you run your function you will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'num_select' of undefined` thus nothing else happens

Answer (score 0):

Normally you might put this in some input fields, check those values (check for not a number) and output to some element on the page.  Here I use a spin button click for the spin action. Example.

```js
var money = 200;

function spin() {
  var landing = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  var nsvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("num_select").value);
  var betvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("bet").value);
  if(!isNaN(nsvalue)&& !isNaN(betvalue))
  if (landing === nsvalue) {
    document.getElementById("action").innerText =("You win $" + betvalue * 3);
    money = money + (betvalue * 3);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("action").innerText =("You lose $" + betvalue);
    money = money - betvalue;
  }
//something here to show spin value perhaps?
}
document.getElementById("spinme").onclick = function(event) {
  spin();
  document.getElementById("results").innerText = ("You currently have $" + money);
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
  empty
</div>
<div id="regular_roulette">
  <label>Choice
    <input id="num_select">
  </label>
  <label>Bet
    <input id="bet">
  </label>
</div>
<button id="spinme">
  Spin!
</button>
<div id="action">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a global variable. you can try to pass it to the function and return it and reassign it.

```
var money = 200;

        function spin(m){



                    var landing = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;   

                    var nsvalue = parseInt(document.regular_roulette.num_select.value);

                    var betvalue = parseInt(document.regular_roulette.bet.value);


                    if (landing === nsvalue)
                    {
                        alert("You win $" + betvalue * 3);

                        m = m + (betvalue * 3);


                    }

                    else
                    {
                        alert("You lose $" + betvalue);

                        m = m - betvalue;


                    }
                    return m;
        }

    money = spin(m);

    document.write("You currently have $" + money);
```